# Alternate Of Group_Concat Function in spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am facing an issue when using group_concat function in spark.

I tried collect_list already, but it seems that is not working:

```
val secItemListDF = hiveCtx.sql(
      s"""SELECT secrecy_party_id  ,coalesce(group_concat(secrecy_reason_cd), 'DEFAULT') secrecy_item  , ${intMaxBatchId} + dense_rank() over(ORDER BY group_concat(secrecy_reason_cd))
         | AS secrecy_key FROM secrecy_party_list l""".stripMargin)
```

As in the query, i am using group_concat but this group_concat function is not supported by Spark and says undefined function when executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect_set`(to neglect duplicates) or `collect_list`(to retain duplicates as well)

Comment: Thanks Sathiyan for your inputs, I have resolved the issue by using UDF.

Comment: @RamJaiswal can you please post the UDF used?